# Transition when show/hide of the div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to show transition when the DIV with the class .socialmenu is shown or hidden. This is the CSS code but it's not working:

```
.socialmenu {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 30px;
    background: #333;
    position: fixed;
    display: none;
    transition: 3s all ease;
}
```

Here's the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qerj9LvL/) with the full code. I don't mind if the transition/animation would be achieved using jQuery too. Any help?

Comment: Instead of show/hide you can use fadeIn/fadeOut or slideDown/slideUp.

Comment: I actually tried that already but it didn't work. I do't see any difference when I use fadeIn/fadeOut while slideDown/slideUp moves the .socialmenu weirdly as I scroll. Both doesn't give the desire effect though.

Comment: Looks like the animation does not work when you set a transition effect in css. I removed `transition: 3s;`. now fadein/fadeout is working: http://jsfiddle.net/qerj9LvL/2/

Comment: Great!! Didn't realize there's a conflict. Thank you. Please post as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use fadeIn(); fadeOut(); instead of hide(); show(); 
Also remove transition effect from .socialmenu class